# AutoMapper AfterMap without Generics

Tags: c#, generics, automapper

I need to set up an `AfterMap` for `AutoMapper` but I'm not using the generic version as I'm creating the maps as needed at run time. If I use the generic version I do this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DALEntity, BLLEntity>()
    .AfterMap((DALEntity dalEntity, BLLEntity bllEntity) =>
        (bllEntity as DomainEntityBase).State = DomainEntityState.Unchanged);
```

Works fine. The other maps which I don't know until run time I am creating like this:

```
Type BLLClassType = Type.GetType(BLLClassName);
Type DALClassType = Type.GetType(DALClassName);
Mapper.CreateMap(DALClassType, BLLClassType);
```

But now I can't set `AfterMap`. Any suggestions? I just need to set the `State` property of the `bllEntity` after AutoMapper has done its bit.

Comment: I don't think this necessarily helps, but for run-time mapping I think you can use [`Mapper.DynamicMap`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740362/automapper-why-use-map-over-dynamicmap) rather than need to create the maps each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create custom value resolver:

```
public class StateResolver : IValueResolver
{
    public ResolutionResult Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
    {
        return source.New(DomainEntityState.Unchanged);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Type BLLClassType = Type.GetType(BLLClassName);
Type DALClassType = Type.GetType(DALClassName);

Mapper.CreateMap(DALClassType, BLLClassType)
      .ForMember("State", opt => opt.ResolveUsing<StateResolver>());
```

Comment: OOh one question - does that get run after AutoMapper has done its own copy? Problem is the other setters which automapper will fire set State - and I need this to reset state to unchanged after the other copies.

Comment: @RBrowning99 I think this will run in same order, as mapping State property without custom settings. Sorry, need to go, will be back in few hours

Comment: Hey, I looked at this and it doesn't change the firing order. The order seems to be alpabetical within the calling class, then up the hierarchy. I've fix my issue for now with a horrible kludge by putting my State property in a parent class so it does indeed get fire last, but I really need the AfterMap as I need this to take place after the map. So it is not possible to use AfterMap with the non generic version? Best Ray

Comment: @RBrowning99 as far as I know, AfterMap is not available for non-generic mapping. Consider changing State property behavior - instead of changing it when you set other properties, make it calculated from other properties value.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be an `AfterMap`? For example, could you use `UseValue` like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DALEntity, BLLEntity>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.State,
               opt => opt.UseValue(DomainEntityState.Unchanged));
```

Comment: Types unknown until runtime - you can't use these generic methods.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the quick response. Doesn't have to be AfterMap - .ForMember would be fine - but I can't seem to get that correct either. What you wrote won't work for me because you are still using generics - with the generics either the AfterMap or Formember would work - but in this case my types are determined at run-time:   Mapper.CreateMap(DALClassType, BLLClassType); I tried using ForMember but I can't seem to get a typecast to work in there, which I think I need to do. Best Ray

Comment: @Lazy Sorry, yeah. I know its a runtime issue, the code was just an example to show how it might work. I couldn't check here to see if it actually did or not, and unfortunately it looks like it doesn't :(